# Is "Ils ont mis leur manteau" correct?

Tags: pluriel

I would normally write "Ils ont mis leur manteaux", but I have recently read "Ils ont mis leur manteau" in a language forum. Is using the singular like that correct, when there is one item of the object for each item of the subject?